# Check if entry exist in a database

Tags: java, android, sql

I want to check if an entry exist in my database.

I've tried:

```
private void saveIt() {     
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_2);

    myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);    
    Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE idwp= '" + id + "'", null);
    if(c == null)
    {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.b);
        try {
            myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+MY_DATABASE_TABLE+" (titel, extra, html) VALUES ('"+titel.replace("'", "\"")+"','"+extra.replace("'", "\"")+"','"+html.replace("'", "\"")+"');");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myDB != null)
                myDB.close();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    myDB.close();
}
```

But always it says "already exist". I've seen my database. There is no entry where `id = xxx`!

Thanks for helping!

**UPDATE:**
I've find a misstake:
INSERT INTO ... extra, html, **id** <- I forget the id!

This is a great community to solve problems!

Comment: Please post your DDL. Chances are, your PK is something other than you think.

Comment: DDL = Data definition language. Basically your table's CREATE TABLE statement, along with definition of Primary Key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Cursor won't be `null` but it might be *empty*, you need to use this:

```
if(c.getCount() > 0) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else {
    // Does not exist!
}
```

You can also use any of the `Cursor#move` methods, since they return `true` or `false` depending on whether there is valid data in the Cursor.

Comment: Look at your query now. Is `id` a number? If so, by surrounding the number in quotes you are using it as a string... Try `" WHERE idwp= " + id`.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE idwp= '" + id + "'", null);
    if(c == null)
    {
```

to:

```
Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE idwp= '" + id + "'", null);
    if(c.getCount() == 0 )
    {
```

Comment: If I insert your code: There will be always 'saved' / not exist -message. Also on items which where not saved :(